# Convert single row to a column in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, reshape2

I have a data frame that has serveral columns along with sub-columns and it looks like this:

[image]

I want to transform this data frame and make a new column from second row which can be considered as a sub column:

[image]

For reproducibility, I have used the code to create the data frame and in this data frame, the second row should be considered a sub-column.

```
df <- data.frame(
      c("Reporting Month", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4"),
      c(202201, 30, 77, 73, 56),
      c(202202, 5, 47, 91, 30),
      c(202203, 44, 10, 68, 62),
      c(202201, 13, 86, 26, 45),
      c(202202, 70, 3, 92, 5),
      c(202203, 29, 61, 8, 23),
      c(202201, 65, 76, 70, 55),
      c(202202, 27, 41, 73, 75),
      c(202203, 10, 47, 72, 12)
    )

colnames(df) <- c("ID", rep("Metric 1", 3), rep("Metric 2", 3), rep("Metric 3", 3))
```

[image]

Let me know in case of any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

If Tidyverse is OK then perhaps something like this:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
library(tidyr)

# combine colnames with 1st row
colnames(df) <- paste(colnames(df), df[1,], sep = "_")
# [1] "ID_Reporting Month" "Metric 1_202201"    "Metric 1_202202"    "Metric 1_202203"  ...

df %>% 
  # drop 1st row (4x10 data.frame)
  slice(-1) %>% 
  # pivot longer, month & metric to separte columns (36x4 tibble)
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Metric"), names_to = c("metric", "month"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
  # pivot longer, (3) metrics to their own columns (12x5 tibble)
  pivot_wider(names_from = "metric") %>% 
  rename(ID = `ID_Reporting Month`, `Reporting Month` = month) %>% 
  arrange(`Reporting Month`, ID)
```

Result:

```r
#> # A tibble: 12 × 5
#>    ID     `Reporting Month` `Metric 1` `Metric 2` `Metric 3`
#>    <chr>  <chr>                  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 Type 1 202201                    30         13         65
#>  2 Type 2 202201                    77         86         76
#>  3 Type 3 202201                    73         26         70
#>  4 Type 4 202201                    56         45         55
#>  5 Type 1 202202                     5         70         27
#>  6 Type 2 202202                    47          3         41
#>  7 Type 3 202202                    91         92         73
#>  8 Type 4 202202                    30          5         75
#>  9 Type 1 202203                    44         29         10
#> 10 Type 2 202203                    10         61         47
#> 11 Type 3 202203                    68          8         72
#> 12 Type 4 202203                    62         23         12
```

Input data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  c("Reporting Month", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4"),
  c(202201, 30, 77, 73, 56),
  c(202202, 5, 47, 91, 30),
  c(202203, 44, 10, 68, 62),
  c(202201, 13, 86, 26, 45),
  c(202202, 70, 3, 92, 5),
  c(202203, 29, 61, 8, 23),
  c(202201, 65, 76, 70, 55),
  c(202202, 27, 41, 73, 75),
  c(202203, 10, 47, 72, 12)
)

colnames(df) <- c("ID", rep("Metric 1", 3), rep("Metric 2", 3), rep("Metric 3", 3))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Awesome, perfect, works best. Thanks!